# how to add content to the right structural block in magento

Tags: magento

how do i  manage which blocks go inside the right structural block.

ie with

getChildHtml('right') ?>

- i want to add some custom code that will go on all pages that use the "right" structural block
- i know i can over the individual elements but i would prefer it is the elements i don't use don't get called.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a layout XML file that will update the right column with your custom blocks.
If you don't know what I'm talking about, then read [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide)

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this in your layout file:

```
<default>
    <reference name="right">
        <!-- Adding your block(s) -->
        <block type="yourmodule/yourblock" name="yourblock" as="yourblock" />

        <!-- Removing some other default block -->
        <remove name="some.other.block.name" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

This should let you control all blocks in the right column.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe